# capture many photos, display & save them in android

Tags: android, camera, save

I 'm working on a new apps for android , that ask the user about how many image he would like to capture, display all & then save.

The number of captured photos works correctly, but when I go to the display's layout only the one photo is shown, I tried "switch" instead of writing them all but nothing seems to work.

Is there any specific code may do that ?!

Comment: Hello Sarah, have you found the solution ? because , now I am on same situation, can you help me please ?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, no. The only way to achieve this is by doing that separately. That's what I know. Good luck :)